# How to merge symbol name and symbol value in C preprocessor

Tags: c++, c, casting, c-preprocessor

The idea is to create automatic caster which would paste pointer to the variable based on given prefix and number.
Lets say you have some interface which is continously developed so you get some new structure versions every couple of weeks. So instead of writing explicity "(structure1*), (structure2*)" and so on you could just use SOME_DEFINE(thisStructure, version); which would handle the case

I thought that this would do the trick

```
#define d1(x) x
#define d2(x,y) x##y

void someFunction()
{
    int temp = 3;
    d2(myStructure,d1(temp)) *thisStruct;
}
```

i was hoping that preprocessor would nest itself and paste d1 operation first and then merge result of d1 operation with first d2 argument. However it doesnt work, so my question is, how can i achive this cause it seems to be possible.

Comment: The question is unclear. Can you give example of what you exactly want? May be you can eliminate the need of preprocessor.

Comment: @user1079475, why do you need d1 preprocessor?

Comment: @Anon: Obviously this is a contrived example.

Comment: You could look into the boost preprocessor library, especially `BOOST_PP_CAT`

Comment: Listen `temp` comes into existance compile time if you want to put that temp value in preprocessor .. you can't do it

Comment: @user1079475, update your question with a proper example adding the same explanation.

Comment: All you need to do is #define version as a preprocessor macro ... trying to use a C variable like temp makes no sense at all since temp's value is determined at run time and even if it were constant the **pre** processor knows nothing about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define d2(x,y) x ## y

void someFunction()
{
    int temp = 3;
    d2(myStructure,temp) *thisStruct;
}
```

The preprocessor converts this to:

```
void someFunction()
{
    int temp = 3;
    myStructuretemp *thisStruct;
}
```

If you want to replace the '3' in there so you get myStructure3, then you cannot do that with the preprocessor - it doesn't know anything about C/C++ variables or their values.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but the usual problem
here is that the preprocessor does token pasting and stringization
before it does macro replacement within its arguments.  So if you write
something like:

```
#define PASTE(a,b) a ## b
```

and call it:

```
#define x 123
PASTE(A,x)
```

, the last line expands to `Ax`, and not to `A123`.  To get the desired
results, it is often necessary to add a level of indirection:

```
#define PASTEHELPER(a,b) a ## b
#define PASTE(a,b) PASTEHELPER(a,b)
```

This works because full macro expansion of the arguments to `PASTE` will
take place before `PASTEHELPER` is expanded, so in `PASTE(A,x)`, above,
the arguments to `PASTEHELPER` will be `A` and `123`.

Comment: This is an explanation of what OP is currently doing; not an answer. The question itself is not clear.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. However it wont work because it will just pass the name of value b to the PASTEHELPER and merge both names instead of one name and one value.

Comment: Dont use temp ..its variable not a macro

Comment: So there is no possible way to do it. The whole idea was to avoid writing case statements, which is mandatory in case of specifying value of argument b

Comment: @user1079475 Then I haven't figured out what you're trying to do.  (Note that the preprocessor deals strictly with text, before the code is parsed, so all it can do is paste tokens.)

Comment: @user1079475 'However it wont work because it will just pass the name of value b to the PASTEHELPER and merge both names instead of one name and one value' -- Yes it does work and you are wrong. Of course it fails if b is a C variable name -- it's incoherent to expect that to expand. But it does work for preprocessor macros like x in the example ... try it before saying it doesn't work.

Comment: @user1079475 'So there is no possible way to do it.' -- It's really quite bizarre to make this claim. This answer gives you a way, but you seem not to want the help. You were told why your use of temp, a C variable, doesn't work but you paid no attention to that. If you don't come back to this and realize that you were given your solution, it will be suitable karma.

Comment: @Jim Balter True i didnt notice that x is a define. However maybe you could hold your horses, because i cant approve more than one answer so i just ranked it up. Yes it cannot be done, and if you think otherwise than you just negate your own words.

Comment: @user1079475 'i cant approve more than one answer' -- you can change which one you approve. 'Yes it cannot be done' -- yes, of course it can, if version is a macro. 'if you think otherwise than you just negate your own words' -- that makes no sense.

Comment: @JimBalter I dont think i can stand it any longer. So please tell me what is your solution for case like this //Structures struct InterfaceScreen0; struct InterfaceScreen1; struct InterfaceScreen2 ...

void allocate_memory(void* structToAlloc, int version)
{
...///handle yourself without a switch :]
}

Comment: @user1079475 There is a well-known solution to such problems but, as I said, I'm not going to help you further.